# Most well-known books translated into Esperanto?

Tags: culture, books

What are the most well-known books that have been translated into Esperanto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Hobbit** by J.R.R. Tolkien Also known as *"La Hobito".*

**The Wonderful Wizard of Oz** by Frank L. Baum Also known as, *"La Mirinda Sorĉisto de Oz"*

**Winnie the Pooh** or *"Winnie la Pu"*

**TinTin in Tibet** or *"Tintin au Tibet"*

A few titles of **Sherlock Holmes** and some of **Edgar Allen Poe**'s work.

There is also a copy of **Alice in Wonderland** and **Alice Through the Looking Glass**.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the books in the other answer, some other well-known books that have been translated are:

- *The Neverending Story*
- *Jane Eyre*
- *The Little Prince*
- *The Alchemist*
- Some books of *Asterix* and *Tintin*

There is also an unofficial translation of Harry Potter but sadly it was never published because the translators were not able to get permission, despite a long campaign and a petition. It is however attainable in the dark corners of the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Among English speakers, I believe the most famous books that have been translated into Esperanto are probably *The Hobbit* by J. R. R. Tolkien and *1984* by George Orwell. There are, of course,  translations of The Holy Bible and other traditional stories and fables.

Answer (score 2):

There are also several charming translations of *Alice in Wonderland*. But with all the made up words (in English, and therefore Esperanto) you might go crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Of particular significance are the translations Zamenhof did to act as a model for the language:

```
The Battle of Life by Charles Dickens (1891)
Hamlet by William Shakespeare (1894)
The Government Inspector by Nikolaj Gogol (1907)
The Robbers by Friedrich Schiller (1907)
Iphigenia in Tauris by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe (1907)
Marta by Eliza Orzeszko (1910)
```